# Can't show how many Views for particular question

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, views

Recently i have open SO in my `Mobile Browser (Chrome)` and particular question. but the page can't show me how many `Views` on that particular question?

I tried to scroll up and down but there is no `View` count like we have in Desktop site.

### Mobile Screen shot:

[image]

### Desktop site screen shot:

[image]

Comment: In a similar breath, 3 people have starred it (including yourself) in the Desktop view, while there seems to be no-one who has starred in the mobile view.